# Why MongoDB saves Hash value in different format?

Tags: mongodb, hash, mongodb-query, ipfs, ipfs-http-client

I am learning IPFS and trying to save `IPFS` file info in MongoDB. After uploading, I get one hash value

```
ex: {fileHash: CID(QmbCaWPi9tSqcnykvBUMaH2M1d5PiVPLEfPwhJksSSeMak)}
```

And in MongoDB, I see something like this:

```
"fileHash": {
    "code": 112,
    "version": 0,
        "multihash": {
            "code": 18,
             "size": 32,
             "digest": "vxaISoMOXTpFy9rwnYilyk7pa6TlhkFDCZgcjGhXfm0=",
             "bytes": "EiC/FohKgw5dOkXL2vCdiKXKTulrpOWGQUMJmByMaFd+bQ=="
       },
    "bytes": "EiC/FohKgw5dOkXL2vCdiKXKTulrpOWGQUMJmByMaFd+bQ=="
}
```

Now I want to update this document based on `hash` value but don't understand what value I compare in match.

```
 db.collection("test").update(filter, set);
```

I was trying like this:

```
db.collection("test").update({fileHash:"CID(QmbCaWPi9tSqcnykvBUMaH2M1d5PiVPLEfPwhJksSSeMak)"}, set);
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think `CID()` is like a function.

When you use `CID("QmbCaWPi9tSqcnykvBUMaH2M1d5PiVPLEfPwhJksSSeMak")`, it come up with a JSON.

```
{
    "code": 112,
    "version": 0,
        "multihash": {
            "code": 18,
             "size": 32,
             "digest": "vxaISoMOXTpFy9rwnYilyk7pa6TlhkFDCZgcjGhXfm0=",
             "bytes": "EiC/FohKgw5dOkXL2vCdiKXKTulrpOWGQUMJmByMaFd+bQ=="
       },
    "bytes": "EiC/FohKgw5dOkXL2vCdiKXKTulrpOWGQUMJmByMaFd+bQ=="
}
```

So you should try something like

```
let fileHash = CID("QmbCaWPi9tSqcnykvBUMaH2M1d5PiVPLEfPwhJksSSeMak");
db.collection("test").update({fileHash: fileHash }, set);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take that CID and use the method `toString()` on it.